# How do I bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element?

Tags: jquery

I do not understand how to get change event to call a function.

```
$(function () {

  function foo() {
    alert("ok");
  }

  //works
  $('#myElement').change(function() {
    alert("ok");
  });

  //does not work
  $('#myElement').change(foo);

  //does not work
  $('#myElement').change(foo());
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or just no activity?

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/t5aAn/).

Comment: @lonesomeday - You have not put the code in a private scope, like the example. You are not comparing the same things.

Comment: @Oded True. I thought jsFiddle did that for you. It seems not!

Comment: Although [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/t5aAn/2/) does work. All I did was close the `$()` call...

Comment: @Oded: Why would that matter? The code in the question is all in the same scope. The first two should work.

Comment: @all the example code posted does in fact work. In my efforts to debug my script I never took it down to this basic form. Going back now, I am finding that it is something totally different. Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the following examples ***should work***, if not then you are doing something wrong.

```
$(function() {
   function foo(e) {
     alert("ok");
   }
   $('#myElement').change(function(e) {
     alert("ok");
   });
   $('#myElement').change(foo);

   //trigger the event like so:
   $('#myElement').change();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob - you are correct, I was doing something wrong. Once I took my code to the basics as posted in the question, it does function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myElement').change(function() {
    foo();
  });
```

Comment: @Oded: So did I. Works fine. Why wouldn't it? [Try it out.](http://jsfiddle.net/7Tk2h/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('#myElement').change(foo);
```

In your code example you are missing one closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

versions 1 and 2 work for me on FF3.6 and IE7. version 3 executes right away because of the presence of the parenthesis. Can you give the browser on which version 2 is not working.

Answer (score 0):

to bind a function to the change event :
`$('#id').bind('change',function(){/*code here*/});`
and to trigger the event :
`$('#id').trigger('change');`